# How to solve "No Python interpreter configured for the module"? in Android Studio?

Tags: python, django, android-studio, kotlin

How to solve "**No Python interpreter configured for the module**"? in Android Studio? I am trying to use **python** and **django framework** in **android studio** . My MainActivity is in kotlin.

[image]

i dont know how to solve this, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Python interpretor in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667573/how-to-configure-python-interpretor-in-android-studio)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to configure Python interpretor in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54678270/4325604)

Answer (score 0):

You can just click on "Configure Python Interpreter", and then locate the place where you downloaded Python.

Comment: I am using android studio, where i can find it?

Comment: It should be to the right of the warning message, under the list of opened files. I use PyCharm, so I am not sure, but also try on the bottom right. Click on where it says Python (your version). If all JetBrains works the same, it should be to the left of the inspection profile and read-only buttons. Then click interpreter settings. Then click the settings icon on the top-right, and click add. Then click "System Interpreter" on the left. Choose the location of the interpreter (python.exe).

Comment: Can you also show me the bottom left of your screen. It should be near Event Log, encoding, and a lock icon.